# Java 8 on Big Sur reports os.name as "Mac OS X" and os.version as "10.16"

Tags: java, macos-big-sur

Is it just my setup or is anyone else having this problem?

Using AdoptOpenJDK 1.8.0_275 installed at:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

API docs of [System.getProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) do not specify any details.

Comment: Why is it a problem?

Comment: Maybe "Mac OS Big Sur" or "Mac OS 11", don't know (in answer to your edited comment that was 'what did you expect')

Comment: And for the version I would expect "11.1" or similar.

Comment: According to [Ars Technica](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/11/macos-11-0-big-sur-the-ars-technica-review/) "Big Sur can still identify itself as version 10.16 to some older software in order to preserve compatibility". I don't know what qualifies as "older software".

Comment: Ok I didn't know that. I was just looking at the about screen on the mac and there it said 11.1, so I was confused.

Comment: Now I wonder if I have to handle both 10.16 and 11.x, depending whether the program is run with java 8 or java 11 etc.

Comment: Accepting both possible version descriptions sounds reasonable.

Comment: @RetoHöhener See my answer - if adoptopenjdk14 and openjdk's own 16-ea all still give 10.16, I doubt you need to take 11.1 into account at this point in time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can confirm this is still happening on adoptopenjdk14, as well as openjdk early access build for j16.

You can file a bug if you want, but I bet it'll be denied. At this point, the name `Mac OS X` is not so much 'the name of the OS' as a 'globally agreed upon keyword identifying that unix-based mac operating system', where I mean globally literally (as in, 'around the planet', not 'across your source base/VM'). Changing it would just break stuff needlessly. The same applies, to a lesser degree, to version 10.16: The thing before the dot is not so much 'this is how the OS identifies itself' and more a 'globally agreed upon versioning scheme for Mac OS, identifying a wide and ill defined set of capabilities'.

There is no meaningful difference between the transition between big sur and catalina, other than the fact that apple made a marketing decision. If you want to point at an OS transition that might warrant the entirely nebulous choice to consider it a 'major change', surely it was the one *to* catalina, as that made by far the largest changes (including removing support for 32-bit entirely) in the last bunch of releases.

This leaves you with the challenge of: Okay, great, I can use `System.getProperty("os.name")` to get the globally agreed upon keyword that means unix-like Mac OS, and os.version for a string I can break into bits to figure out some nebulous batch of capabilities, but what if I need the *actual name* of the OS to e.g. show to a user?

Then you have three major options:

1. The easy one is to just write mapping code. Acknowledge that `os.name` and `os.version` give you (rather arguably) useful intent and not so much official names, and therefore, write some mappings. These would map name/version pairs to rendering strings, falling back to just printing the name string and the version string, concatenated, verbatim. You could add a mapping: `Mac OS X/10.16` → `Mac OS Big Sur` in this table.
2. The hard way: Figure out you're on a mac (which is now easier; `os.name` returns `Mac OS X`, or just check for the existence: `Files.isExecutable(Paths.get("/usr/bin/sw_vers"))`), and then use `ProcessBuilder` to execute `/usr/bin/sw_vers`, picking up all output into a big string, and then parse it. Its output looks like:

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.1
BuildVersion:   20C69
```

which, crucially, doesn't even include the words `Big Sur`, but does give you `11.1`. I don't know how to run a command line tool that actually gives you `Big Sur`. Maybe `system_profiler`, but note that this takes many minutes to run, I really doubt you want to run that.

NB: you can also run `.command("/usr/bin/sw_vers", "-productVersion")` which gives you just `11.1`, this may be a lot simpler to parse. `-productName` also works, gives you just `macOS`.

3. If you need this information to scan for OS capabilities, then stop doing this. It doesn't work with browsers, and it's not a good plan for OS releases either. What capability are you scanning for? Imagine, for example, if it is 'Can I run /usr/bin/sw_vers to figure stuff out', as a hypothetical example. The right strategy is **NOT** to check os.name/os.version, conclude that the command must exist, and then run it, failing catastrophically if it is not there. The right move is to check if /usr/bin/sw_vers exists, and then execute it, falling back to some non-mac based solution (perhaps /usr/bin/uname) in other cases. Scan for the capability, don't scan for the OS/version.

Comment: Luckily I don't need to display the name of the operating system (yet). I was mainly just observing some log output and got confused. One thing we will surely have to do is teach support to interpret our log files correctly (they will be confused as well).

Comment: I'm searching for some oracle docs that specify this behavior about os.version for MacOS...

Comment: I'd be _extremely_ surprised if you find that. Most likely they are invoking some apple-level API which is returning 10.16 (see notes about Ars Technica article), and oracle will then, if you file a bug, agree that apple's choice to return 10.16 instead of 11.1 applies exactly the same to their situation and thus refuse to change it, and if I know oracle and bug reports, they love closing em with bizarre reasons and do nothing, so no docs would be forthcoming. Most likely, the docs already say 'just parrots what the OS told us', and they'd point at this as sufficient. I kinda agree, even.

Comment: To be clear, I don't think `if (version.equals("11.1")) return "10.16";` or something along those lines is anywhere in the openjdk sources.

Comment: Accepting this for now, until some offical specs from Oracle or OpenJDK appear (which I agree is unlikely to happen).

Answer (score 1):

## Java code to call native tool `sw_vers`

Regarding Option # 2 in the [Answer by rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66026906/642706), here is a complete code example to run from Java a command-line tool `sw_vers` that describes the version of macOS software running on the host computer.

If on the command-line (console) such as in Terminal.app, you run:

```sh
sw_vers
```

…in Big Sur on an Intel Mac we get:

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.2
BuildVersion:   20D64
```

We only need the middle piece. So running:

```sh
sw_vers -productVersion
```

…shows simply `11.2`, the value we need for your purpose.

Here is complete example app with a method to return this string into Java.

[`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class creates operating system processes. Each new process is represented by the [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html) class.

We use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close the `InputStream` and `Scanner` objects.

Once you have the `11.2` string in hand, split on the FULL STOP, pull the first number `11`, and you know you are running on Big Sur.

```java
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Example code showing how to get current version of macOS from Java
 * by running a native command-line tool `sw_vers`.
 */
public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        String version = this.getMacOsVersionNumber();
        System.out.println( "version = " + version );
    }

    public String getMacOsVersionNumber ( )
    {
        String result = "";
        List < String > command = List.of( "sw_vers" , " -productVersion" );
        try (
                InputStream inputStream = new ProcessBuilder( command ).start().getInputStream() ;
                Scanner s = new Scanner( inputStream ).useDelimiter( "\\A" ) ;
        )
        {
            result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Objects.requireNonNull( result );
    }
}
```